# Laravel: Same table, One-to-One relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a customers table with a spouse field, I'm referencing that foreign key with:

```
$table->integer('spouse')->nullable();
$table->foreign('spouse')->references('customerId')->on('customers');
```

My problem is, how do I set the function to return the `belongsTo()` and `hasOne()` if I can only have one function named `spouse()`:

```
public function spouse()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Customer');
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll only need to define one function:

```
# Customer.php

public function spouse()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Customer');
}
```

Then, when link the objects, **relate the objects with each other**:

```
# CustomersController.php

$person_a = Customer::find(1);
$person_b = Customer::find(2);
$person_a->spouse()->save($person_b);
$person_b->spouse()->save($person_a);
```

Then to use it:

```
# CustomersController.php

$person_a = Customer::find(1);
$person_b = $person_a->spouse;
$person_a = $person_b->spouse;
```

---

### Observation

When defining a relationship with a foreign key different to `{model}_id`, you need to specify it when defining the relationship (check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)):

```
# Customer.php

public function spouse()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Customer', 'spouse');
}
```

Also, this foreign key column needs to be `unsignedInteger()` (in case of the primmary key is a `integer`) or `bigUnsignedInteger()` in case the foreign primmary key is `bigInteger`:

If:

```
$table->increments('customerId');
```

do:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('spouse')->nullable();
$table->foreign('spouse')->references('customerId')->on('customers');
```

Or, if:

```
$table->bigIncrements('customerId');
```

do:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('spouse')->nullable();
$table->foreign('spouse')->references('customerId')->on('customers');
```